# Inline SQL function which sometimes must update database

Tags: sql, sql-server, inline-functions

Is it possible to create a function/procedure, which could be used in a SQL statement like this:

`INSERT INTO Journal(ProductID,Quantity) VALUES(LookupOrCreateProduct('12345678'),5)`

`LookupOrCreateProduct` should look up a product table by string (barcode) and:
* If barcode is found - return Product ID
* If barcode is not found - create a new record in Products table with new barcode and return its ID

I explored SQL Server functions, but they do not allow `INSERT`s or any other database modification inside function body. Stored procedures can return values, but they can only be of `int` type. My ID column is `bigint`. Another option is to use output parameter but then it is not clear to me, how can I inline it in SQL statement. Thank you.

Comment: Set output parameter of Bigint datatype and return it from stored procedure and save it into variable and then use it for your insert query...

Comment: You can't do that with a function. [And you should use an OUTPUT parameter, not a RETURN value](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output.aspx). RETURN values are for error / status codes, not for data; one of the primary reasons is exactly what you've discovered: they're only useful for ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LookupOrCreateProduct 
   @BarCode    VARCHAR(100),
   @ProductID  BIGINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;


       SELECT TOP 1 @ProductID = ProductID
       FROM dbo.Products 
       WHERE BarCode = @BarCode

   IF(@ProductID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.Products(Barcode)
      VALUES (@BarCode)

      SET @ProductID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END   

END
```

Comment: Why the `IF EXISTS` check? Even if BarCode is indexed, this is a wasteful extra check. `SELECT @ProductID =` ... `IF @ProductID IS NULL` then insert.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Certainly it makes more sense this way, thank you for the pointer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is an output parameter in a stored procedure:

```
declare @product_id int;

begin transaction;

exec dbo.LookupOrCreateProduct '12345678', @product_id out;

insert into journal (productId, quantity) values (@product_id, 5);

commit transaction;
```